# Отправить ответ на soap запрос PHP

Tags: php, curl, soap

Добрый день. Есть некий сервер который отправляет мне такой SOAP запрос:

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bus="http://www.xxx.com/xxxserver">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bus:GetCustomerInformation>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bus:CardNumber>1234567890</bus:CardNumber>
      </bus:GetCustomerInformation>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Я должен ответить на него вот в таком формате:

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetCustomerInformationResponse xmlns="http://www.xxx.com/xxxserver">
         <GetCustomerInformationResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ExternalCustomerSoapServer" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:CardNumber>1234567890</a:CardNumber>
            <a:City>Dfcity</a:City>
            <a:CityExtra i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Email>vasiapupkin@sobaka.ru</a:Email>
            <a:EmployeeNumber i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Fax i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Gender>M</a:Gender>
            <a:IsBlocked>false</a:IsBlocked>
            <a:IsInactive>false</a:IsInactive>
            <a:LanguageCode i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Name i:nil="true"/>
            <a:NationCode i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Phone>8800000000</a:Phone>
            <a:PoBox i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Street>Lenina</a:Street>
            <a:StreetExtra i:nil="true"/>
            <a:StreetNumber>1</a:StreetNumber>
            <a:StreetNumberExtra i:nil="true"/>
            <a:SurName>PUPKIN</a:SurName>
            <a:ZipCode>1234567</a:ZipCode>
         </GetCustomerInformationResult>
      </GetCustomerInformationResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Как реализовать ответ на своей стороне есть какие то примеры? Читал доки по SOAP на php.net очень сложные доки для нуба. Можно ли использовать curl? Или какой другой способ?

Comment: Чисто теоретически никто не мешает вот этот вот текст вывести с помощью PHP. Простыми echo. Ну а вообще, все же разберитесь с SOAP, хотя конечно это тот еще квест.

Comment: http://yaforyou.ru/?q=soap%20php. Это было сложно, но я смог. Кроме php.net в интернете ресурсов нет. Только вот этот сайт